# How to get last date of month, but hide Sunday and Saturday in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please help.. this my code

```
 DECLARE @StartDT DATE = '2018-03-01' 
 DECLARE @Tanggal AS DATE = '2018-03-01' 
 DECLARE @EndDT DATE = '2018-03-31' 
 DECLARE @Hari AS INT

 --DECLARE @AkhirBulan AS DATE

 WHILE @StartDT <= @EndDT 
 BEGIN
       SET @Hari = DATEPART(dw,@StartDT)
       --SET @EndDT = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@EndDT)+1,0))

       IF @Hari NOT IN (7,1) 
          AND @EndDT IN (DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @EndDT) + 1, 0)))
       BEGIN    
           IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Holiday 
                         WHERE HolidayDate = @StartDT)
           --IF @EndDT IN (@EndDT)          PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@StartDT)--+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@hari )            --EXEC
 DashboardHistory_Insert @Tanggal, @StartDT 
       END

       SET @StartDT = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDT)
       --SELECT EOMONTH ( @StartDT ) END
```

This is the result of my script

```
2018-03-01 2018-03-02 2018-03-05 2018-03-06 2018-03-07 2018-03-08 2018-03-09 2018-03-12 2018-03-13 2018-03-14 2018-03-15 2018-03-16 2018-03-19 2018-03-20 2018-03-21 2018-03-22 2018-03-23 2018-03-26 2018-03-27 2018-03-28 2018-03-29 2018-03-30
```

*2018-03-31* <- I want to get last of month like this but sunday and saturday not showing

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Sql Server 2012

Comment: You want to display all days in a month except for Sundays and Saturdays?

Comment: Yes sir, but when in of month show last of day on Saturday or Sunday mush showing.. only get last of day in month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far better approach to this would be to not use a `WHILE` on something that can be easily achieved using a set based method. Using a `WHILE` or `CURSOR` is normally an awful idea for something that can be completely by a set based method, as they are slow and scale poorly.

One way of doing this would be to use a Tally, and then build your data set on that. For example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date;
SET @StartDate = '20180301';
SET @EndDate = '20180331';

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) V(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM CTE C1
         CROSS JOIN CTE C2),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,T.I, @StartDate) AS CalendarDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.I DESC) AS Ir
    FROM Tally T
    WHERE T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))
SELECT D.CalendarDate,  DATENAME(WEEKDAY,D.CalendarDate) AS CalendarDay
FROM Dates D
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,D.CalendarDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday') --Note this is language specific
   OR Ir = 1
ORDER BY D.CalendarDate ASC;
```

Comment: Glad it works, @NovaAndriana . Do you understand it?

Comment: yes bro, i'm uderstand.. i'm stack for my problem code one hours Lol :D. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude all the Sundays and Saturdays except if it is the last day of the month then below query will give you the result. Please check and alter the SELECT statement accordingly.

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE='2018-03-01' 
DECLARE @EndDT DATE='2018-03-31' 

WHILE @StartDT <= @EndDT
BEGIN
    IF (DATEPART(DW,@StartDT) = 1 OR DATEPART(DW,@StartDT) = 7 ) AND (EOMONTH(@StartDT)!= @StartDT)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartDT = DATEADD(D,1,@StartDT)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @StartDT
    END
    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(D,1,@StartDT)
END
```

Comment: I agree that this does work, but a set based answer would be far better. Using a `WHILE` loop to achieve something that can be done set based is normally frowned upon; especially as SQL Server excels at set-based operations and performs poorly at iterative processes.

Comment: @Nova Andriana: That's great! Please mark as answered for reference.